# Is there an easy way to get which power of two a number is?

Tags: c

If I have a number that I am certain is a power of two, is there a way to get which power of two the number is? I have thought of this idea:
Having a count and shifting the number right by 1 and incrementing the count until the number is 0. Is there another way, though? Without keeping a counter?

Edit:
Here are some examples:
8 -> returns 3
16 -> returns 4
32 -> returns 5

Comment: complement your number, and then: possible duplicate of [Getting the number of trailing 1 bits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380728/getting-the-number-of-trailing-1-bits)

Comment: See [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious), it has fast methods for any bit-twiddling hacks you can imagine (lookup tables, etc.).

Comment: Almost identical to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994593/how-to-do-an-integer-log2-in-c ; see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478023/index-of-lowest-order-bit

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant method is De Bruijn sequences. Here's a previous answer I gave to a similar question on how to use them to solve the problem:

[Bit twiddling: which bit is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465098/bit-twiddling-which-bit-is-set/3465395#3465395)

An often-more-practical approach is using your cpu's built-in instruction for finding the first/last bit set.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the log function in cmath...

```
double exponent = log(number)/log(2.0);
```

...and then cast it to an int afterwards.

Comment: Not sure about floating precision, but this works on more than just powers of 2!

Answer (score 1):

If that number is called `x`, you can find it by computing `log2f(x)`. The return value is a float.

You will need to include `<math.h>` in order to use `log2f`.

Answer (score 1):

That method certainly would work.  Another possible way would be to eliminate half of the possibilities every time.  Say you have an 8 bit number: 00010000

Bitwise and your number where half of the bits are one, and the other half is zero, say 00001111.

00010000 & 00001111 = 00000000

Now you know it's not in the first four bits.  Do this repeatedly, until you don't get 0:

00010000 & 00110000 = 00010000

And than narrow it down to one possible bit which is 1, which is your power of two.

Answer (score 0):

Use binary search instead of linear:

```
public void binarySearch() throws Exception {
  int num = 0x40000;

  int k = 0;
  int shift = 16; // half of the size of the type (for in 16, etc)
  int a = 0xffff; // lower half should be f's

  while (shift != 0) {
    if ((num & a) == 0) {
      num = num >>> shift;
      k += shift;
      shift >>= 1;
    } else {
      shift >>= 1;
    }
    a = a >>> shift;
  }
  System.out.println(k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a `for` loop like I am, one method is to power the loop counter before comparison:

```js
for (var i = 1; Math.pow(2, i) <= 1048576; i++) {
  // iterates every power of two until 2^20
}
```